# Is View.show() the same as View.setVisible(true)?

Tags: user-interface, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

Working on making some views of my app's UI more dynamic. Wanted to know if calling View.show() is equivocal to View.setVisible(true) in order to determine if it's redundant for me to call both in my code when wanting a hidden element to appear. Same goes for hiding a UI element. Doesn't seem to throw a fit if I call both.

I would assume the show() method would have to change the View.visible attribute the same way as its respective set() method. Are they essentially the same functions with different names or is there a specific use-case where one should be used over the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the SDK:

- [setVisibility](https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile/blob/166b44b2e3a1290293372f306df7562a332ac057/android/titanium/src/java/org/appcelerator/titanium/view/TiUIView.java#L1268)
- [show](https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile/blob/166b44b2e3a1290293372f306df7562a332ac057/android/titanium/src/java/org/appcelerator/titanium/view/TiUIView.java#L1285)

`show` is calling `setVisibility`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link to the SDK! I completely forgot I could actually view it and I'll definitely be referring to it from here on out.